# XML markup declaration error

Tags: xml, xsd

i am trying to read a XML document which has a referrence to a xsd doc.but when i do this i end up getting "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed" error. dont know what the mistake is.thanks in advance.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE XML SYSTEM "NGPSCustomerConfig.xsd">
<NGPSCustomerConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NGPSCustomerConfg.xsd">
    <CustomerInfo id="NGPS">
        <CustomerName>NGPS</CustomerName>
        <CustomerAdditionalInfo> Additional Info</CustomerAdditionalInfo>
        <ToolInfo>
            <toolName>Service Manager</toolName>
            <toolID>SM01</toolID>
            <toolType>ITSM</toolType>
            <toolProperty>001_SM01.Properties</toolProperty>
        </ToolInfo>
        <ToolInfo>
            <toolName>Orchestrator</toolName>
            <toolID>ORCH01</toolID>
            <toolType>ORCHESTRATOR</toolType>
            <toolProperty>001_ORCH01.properties</toolProperty>
        </ToolInfo>
        <ToolInfo>
            <toolName>Event Manager</toolName>
            <toolID>EM01</toolID>
            <toolType>EVENT MANAGER</toolType>
            <toolProperty>001_EM01.properties</toolProperty>
        </ToolInfo>
    </CustomerInfo>
</NGPSCustomerConfig>
```

The XSD file is

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="NGPSCustomerConfig">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CustomerInfo">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CustomerName" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CustomerAdditionalInfo">
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="ToolInfo" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="toolName" />
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="toolID" />
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="toolType" />
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="toolProperty" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE XML SYSTEM "NGPSCustomerConfig.xsd">
```

says two things:

1. The root element of the following XML document will be named `XML`
2. The file `NGPSCustomerConfig.xsd` is a *DTD* for the document.

Neither of these are true in your case - `NGPSCustomerConfig.xsd` is a schema, not a DTD so the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is sufficient, you don't need the DOCTYPE at all.